# How to send keystrokes to Chrome in Ubuntu?

Tags: keyboard

I would like my computer to press the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key every 2 minutes. How can I do this? With an app or shell script or otherwise?

Comment: to Browser... Chrome!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use [xdotool](http://man.cx/xdotool) [image: Install xdotool]

```
while true; do
   xdotool key Escape
   sleep 120
done
```

You can specify a window with the `--window` option

Comment: Brilliant! I didn't know about that one :)